# How to avoid closing newfd in dup2 function?

Tags: c, linux, file

The scenario is as following:

1. Some threads call fprintf(stderr,...) to print log, stderr is directed to a log file.
2. One thread want to direct stderr to a new file.

However, dup2(fd, 2); stderr will be closed in dup2. The data printed to stderr may lost.
I don't want to use mutex here. Is there any good solution for this case.
Thanks.

Comment: if you use stdio function like `fprintf`, you should use `freopen` instead of dup2 directly. And no, you can't have different stderr for different thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a separate `stderr` per thread. File descriptors (and streams) are shared by all threads in a process.

The best you can is have a mapping of thread to output stream (TLS), which would normally map to `stderr`. In your thread, open another output stream and use it.